# I tried using an image in HTML, why won't it show

Tags: html

[The Code I have tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko6nk.png)

I dont know what mistake I made here, I am retaking a course and going through the image part(I am a newb), however my images never load it just gives me the picture wont load broken face. Help please!

Comment: Try `<img src="../Lesson_2/images/yhplogob.jpg" />` and read more on [Relative File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) and how to use them.

Comment: As a side note, for future questions, please place the _code_ not a _screenshot_ in your question for a better response rate / future question usability/reference. Thanks